# How to clone all row in table

Tags: javascript

Sorry if it's simple problem.
I have

```
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
 <tbody>
 <tr> 
   <td>col1 Val1</td>
   <td>col2 Val2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>col1 Val3</td>
   <td>col2 Val4</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I want copy all row in `tbody` of `table` when user click button `clone`.

This is my code

```
var clnNode=document.getElementById("mytab1").tBodies[0].rows[0].cloneNode(true);
```

And I have `other table` so I pass it like this

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById('table2');
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
newRow.innerHTML= clnNode;
```

That table 2 have html like this

```
            <table id="table2"  border="1">
                <thead>
                   <th>No</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             </tbody>
         </table>
```

but I get `[object HTMLTableRowElement]` to result on browser.

please help me in JavaScript only.

thanks.

Comment: You want to clone tbody, not the first row in it. Leave `rows[0]` out, that should give you the tbody.

Comment: I want all row in tbody

Comment: Sure. Then don't take the first, correct?

Comment: I have try to remove it but still get the same message

Comment: Where do you get the message?

Comment: I get `[object HTMLTableRowElement]` to result on browser.

Comment: Please show us the code actually producing the result.

Comment: please view my edit for more detail

Comment: @Songs mine works great, check it out.

Comment: @Songs `innerHTML` expects a string as a value. You're assigning an object, which is then implicitely converted to a string. Notice, that you're cloning the first row, not `tbody`. A tbody-clone would contain all rows in it. If you don't want to append `tbody` too, you need to iterate it, and append individual rows to another tbody, not to an existing row.

Comment: So any function can copy all row as string ?

Comment: Umh... `tbody.innerHTML` would do that, but please clear out the way you've started with, it's "more correct" having not all the side effects `innerHTML` can have.

Comment: @Songs I have made one that searches through a table for all tr then clones each tr then appends it within the tbody. On every click of button.

Comment: @zer00ne http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253833/1169519

Comment: Watching you two conversate is like watching grass grow, YAWN. -_-ZZZ

Answer (score 0):

you need to append it to `tbody` as well. Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nmd9mubk/) to do it for one row

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var tbody = table1.getElementsByTagName( "tbody" )[ 0 ];
var row1 = tbody.getElementsByTagName( "tr" )[ 0 ];
var clnNode=row1.cloneNode(true);
tbody.appendChild( clnNode );
```

you can add this clone node in another table by doing

```
var table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
var tbody = table1.getElementsByTagName( "tbody" )[ 0 ];
tbody.appendChild( clnNode ); //from previous code
```

Comment: Still can not get, may be because of my code structure

Answer (score 0):

Usage `cloneTR(table)`

- table: Any selector or combination of selectors to target a single table (e.g. '#id', ".class", "tag").

```js
function cloneTR(table) {
  var tbl = document.querySelector(table);
  var tbd = tbl.querySelector('tbody');
  var trList = tbd.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var trArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(trList);
  for (var i = 0; i < trArray.length; i++) {
    var clTR = trArray[i].cloneNode(true);
    tbd.appendChild(clTR);
  }
  return false;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  cloneTR('#table1');
}, false);
```

```css
#table1 {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Clone</button>
<table name="tab" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1 Val1</td>
      <td>col2 Val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col1 Val3</td>
      <td>col2 Val4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Yes your code work fine but when I add it to my project , it's still get the same problem, may be I have something wrong, Thank any ways for your sharing

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need it done another way if you get any ideas as to what might be the problem on your project.

Comment: @Songs I think I might know why it's not working for you. I changed the table's id, so if you only copied the JS but not the markup, then that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

use `.appendChind(node)` method instead `.innerHTML=`.
please refer the below code sample for this case to understand.

```js
var clnNode=document.getElementById("mytab1").tBodies[0].rows[0].cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("mytab1").appendChild(clnNode);
document.getElementById("testNode").innerHTML = clnNode;
```

```html
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
 <tbody>
 <tr> 
   <td>col1 Val1</td>
   <td>col2 Val2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>col1 Val3</td>
   <td>col2 Val4</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
  
 </table> 
 <div id="testNode"></div>
```